# Use HTML character as a background

Tags: html, css, background

I've followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40487478/5765312) to get [this html character](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/black-shogi-piece/) as a background image. It works well but not as a background, the HTML character is on top of the text. I already tried several posibilities but I think there's something out of my knowledge.

```css
.number {position: relative;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
.number::after {
    content: "\2617"; 
    color: blue; 
    margin-left: -1em; 
    font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="number">
90
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `z-index` property:

```css
.background {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -9999;
}
```